# Execute Multiple Python Script Files & Pass values for variables - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using below 3 variables in python script file.

sourcePath, knoxPath, redShiftKeyFolderPath

I want pass the values for these variable & execute them using below script.

```
import sys, subprocess

knoxPath = r"C:\sunil_plus\dataset\knoxFile.xlsx"
redShiftKeyFolderPath = r"C:\sunil_plus\redShift"

sourcePath = 'C:\sunil_plus\dataset\Source1'
subprocess.call([sys.executable, r"D:\Sunil_Work\1_redShift.py", 'htmlfilename.htm']) # want to pass knoxPath, redShiftKeyFolderPath, sourcePath

sourcePath = 'C:\sunil_plus\dataset\Source2'
subprocess.call([sys.executable, r"D:\Sunil_Work\2_redShift.py", 'htmlfilename.htm']) # want to pass knoxPath, redShiftKeyFolderPath, sourcePath

sourcePath = 'C:\sunil_plus\dataset\Source3'
subprocess.call([sys.executable, r"D:\Sunil_Work\3_redShift.py", 'htmlfilename.htm']) # want to pass knoxPath, redShiftKeyFolderPath, sourcePath
```

Also, I want to get the output of script file.

Comment: `r = call(...)`. `r.stdout` gives you what you want.

Comment: any reason why you are trying to call python scripts from your python script instad of importing them?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, data files stored in multiple folders, & I don't want to use import